# Good client-side Gauge control?

Tags: ajax, client-side, gauge

Does anybody know of a good client-side gauge control?  I've tried out ComponentArt's AJAX control, but it's client-side feature leaves a little to be desired.  I'm not looking for a Silverlight or Flash gauge either.  Currently, I'm playing around with Google's Visualization Gauge and it seems to work pretty well.  However, I'd like the control to be more skinnable/customizable if possible.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

assuming you're willing to write for HTML5 browsers...

http://www.digitaldarknet.net/flash/jsgauge.html

Otherwise, make a DIV with a background image that contains another image that you use jQuery to rotate a-la

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-rotate/

Comment: Rotating an image via jQuery seems like an interesting option.  I'll have to look into it...